# How do I copy part of the Java application package structure to a directory on the file system?

Tags: java

My Java app, packaged as a JAR file - app.jar - has the following package structure:

```
com
   company
      pkg1
      pkg2
      help
         dir1
            file1
            ...
         dir2
            subdir1
               files
               ...

      pkg3
      ...
```

From within my application, I'd like to copy everything under com/company/help/ to a directory on the local file system.  What is the best way to do this in java, preferably without resorting to third-party Java libraries?

Comment: A Jar is just a zip file - you could make use of the available zip functionality in the JDK to pull out the elements you want.  Alternatively, as part of your build process you could built a manifest of the files contained with those directories and then at runtime use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream` to get a direct reference ... but this begins to raise questions over why?

Comment: Why? If what's in there is read-only, just access it as resources.

Comment: As others have said: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: If you can _guarantee_ your app is definitely delivered as a jar this is possible. If you can't guarantee that - the classloader mechanism __has no 'list' primitive__, so you'd have to, during build, run `ls build >build/file-list.txt` so that you can ask for that file list so you have a listing.

Comment: Thanks everyone - I gave the reason 'why' I want to do this as comments to @rzwitserloot's suggested answer.  I was hoping the answer suggested a way to somehow recursively descend the package structure starting with Myclass.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/comopany/help")

Comment: I think I will take @rzwitserloot's suggestion of creating the list of files during the build process and then simply iterating over those files using Class.class.getResourceAsStream() to write those files the fs.  I actually also came across an even better solution - the ClassGraph library (see GitHub) - it actually has exactly what i need using just a few lines of code, but I'm doing this to reduce my jar's size - once I add in ClassGraph and all its dependencies, my savings of eliminating that duplicate help.zip in my jar is almost negated by including those jars :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a file name (such as `com/company/pkg1/foo.class`), you can just stick a slash in front and call `AnyClassInThere.class.getResourceAsStream()` to read it. This means, **if** you have a list of files you want to copy, you can write something like:

```
Path target = Path.of("/Users/wolfman/test-copy");
for (String fileName : list) {
  // fileName is something like "com/company/pkg1/Foo.class
  try (var in = ClassThisIsIn.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + fileName)) {
  Path tgt = target.resolve(fileName);
  Files.createDirectories(tgt.getParent());
  try (var out = Files.newOutputStream(tgt)) {
    in.transferTo(out);
  }
}
```

That works regardless of how you ship your app (it doesn't *have to be* in a jar file). That just leaves figuring out how to get that list of files.

The classloader system we use here (`.getResourceAsStream`) simply *does not support* the concept of 'list files'. Hence, what you want using just this, isn't directly possible. There are 2 ways to solve the problem:

### fix it in the build

During build time, 'list files' **is** available. Generally build systems such as maven, gradle, or ant, make a dir such as `build`, pile every file that is about to be put in your jar in there, and then turns that into a jar. If, in between, you can manage to run something like `ls build |grep com/company >build/list-of-files.txt`, then to *get* that file list, you simply read `ClassThisIsIn.class.getResource("/list-of-files.txt")` line by line and voila, there's your list of files.

Every build system can do this, but exactly how depends rather a lot on what you have.

### Assume it's a jar

If you **know** your app is distributed as a jar, you can do this:

```
String url = ClassThisIsIn.class.getResource("ClassThisIsIn.class").toString();
```

Now url will be something like `jar:file:///Users/wolfman/workspace/coolproject/dist/myapp.jar!com/company/base/ClassThisIsIn.class`.

Take a hatchet to that string - use `substring` and the like to extract `/Users/wolfman/workspace/coolproject/dist/myapp.jar`. It's everything after `file:`, before the first `!`, and strip any excess slashes up front.

Then just open that as a `JarFile` or `ZipFile` (jars are zips), and **that** has a 'list' primitive. You can read from there (use `transferTo` as above directly from your JarFile object, bypassing `getResourceAsStream` as in the snippet at the top of this answer), or only use it to create a list of files.

I wouldn't recommend this course of action. Your app now breaks if its distributed in any way other than 'as a jar file'. It'll hamper testing and reduce your productivity when working on it (as it MUST be built into a jar to properly function, you can't debug it inline anymore, or at least, not this bit).

### Closing notes

It's slightly odd to 'want' this. If it's files that are otherwise unrelated to the running of your app, just stick a zip in a zip and open that (so that you don't have to find a way to 'list'). If you want to copy your classes and such - why? If it's some sort of 'install on local disk', maybe just copy the entire jar, or at the very least, make one and stream your files straight into it, save the user some disk space.

Comment: I actually currently do what you suggest in the closing notes - during build, I create a help.zip file and just stick that into the jar and open/write it at startup.  But this zip file is really just a duplicate of what's already in the package structure and the help content is very large, so the zip file substantially increases the size of the overall jar and I was trying to eliminate it.

Comment: Ah, you need it both directly _and_ copy it. That makes sense :)

Comment: Yes, the help is html based and the app's  built-in Swing components can't fully render it, so when help is clicked, I open the desktop browser.  To do that, the help needs to be in the fs.  My app actually also includes a Web server that normally serves the help directly from the package structure, but that is disabled in 'secure' locations, so the help needs to be available locally.

What I was hoping for is a solution that simply recursively descends the package structure via ClassThisIsIn.class.getResourceAsStream().

Comment: Yeah, 'list contents' would be a nice primitive. But, you can't get that, unless you enforce 'this part of the app does not work unless it is in jar form'.